# If force of static friction equals the normal force times a coefficient, why is there no force of friction at rest?

Tags: friction

Now, I know. The question is silly. Why would there be friction if the object is at rest with no force acting upon it?

However, by the inequality $f_s \le \mu_s F_n$, shouldn't there be friction regardless? Because the normal force always has a magnitude, so shouldn't friction have a magnitude, too?

Is this a case where a mathematical model contradicts reality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mu_s F_n$ gives the *maximum* force of friction. The current force of friction is always less than or equal to this, and $0$ is clearly $\leq \mu_s F_n$.

Comment: Yes, I somehow overlooked the inequality and thought if it as an equality.

Answer (score 2):

$0\leq\mu_sF_n$ is still a true inequality since both $\mu_s$ and $F_n$ are non-negative, real numbers, so the mathematics allows for zero static friction.

Comment: Oh yes! I cant believe I actually wrote the inequality but kept thinking about it like $f_s = \mu_s F_n$. Since this is blatantly obvious, should I delete the question?

Comment: @BoredComedy It's a useful question; I wouldn't delete it. There is no policy against "obvious" questions.